# Strange intercept using lmp() in lmPerm library in R

Tags: r

Please consider this data set:

```
y <- c(2, 4, 6)
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

Now calculate a linear model using lmp():

```
library(lmPerm) 
lmp(y ~ x)
```

What I get, but don't understand, is this:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          4            2
```

My question: Why on earth is the intercept given as 4? It should be 0. lm() seems to agree:

```
lm(y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          0            2
```

This is just an example with a small data set. I get similarly disturbing results on my actual data set, even if I tell lmp() to perform 100000 permutations and to stop at Ca=0.0001.

Comment: With such low number of observations, the various samples obtained for the permuation lm have a big influence on the obtained estimates. How many data points does your initial data set have?

Comment: The original data has 48 observations in it. The intercept of lm() and lmp() differ by a factor of 2.5. Plus, intercept and x value should still produce a linear model to fit the data, which is doesn't do very well in none of the trials I made.

Comment: The intercept and slope of lm perm will try to fit all the permuted samples of the original data set. I think with such a low number of observations (especially if you have a lot of variability in your data) you should not use lmPerm but lm.

Comment: ECII, the parameters I'm interested in is the regression fit. Where in the code do you see evidence that the permutation algo is not just used to calculate p-values but also slope and intercept? (Just curious.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn `center=F` you get the coefficients similar to `lm()`

```
y <- c(2, 4, 6)
x <- c(1, 2, 3)

library(lmPerm) 
lmp(y ~ x, center=F)

[1] "Settings:  unique SS "

Call:
lmp(formula = y ~ x, center = F)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          0            2
```

Comment: This seems to work. Why lmPerm chooses to calculate wrong parameters by default is beyond me. That they are wrong is obvious since abline(lmp(...)) draws a regression line way off where it should be unless you supply center=FALSE. Thanks for the info.